# 任意の数字が出てくる回数をそれぞれカウントしたい

Tags: python

下記のようなテキストファイルがあるとします(簡易化しました)
`ABC0001,ABC0001,ABC0002` となっている、1個目の `.` の次の文字列のでてくる回数をそれぞれカウントしたいです。
元ファイルだと右側に `ABC0001` などがでてくる可能性もあるので、場所を指定したうえのものだと助かります。

**元ファイルの例:**

```
100111.ABC0001 100111.ABC2210 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200
100111.ABC0001 100111.ABC2250 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200
100111.ABC0002 100111.ABC3258 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200
```

**期待する結果例:**

```
ABC0001 2
ABC0002 1
```

Comment: 実現したいことに対して **何が分からないのか** をもう少し具体的に記してみてください。現状だと仕様が書かれているだけで、何に困っているのかが分かりません。 / 例えば単純に「1行に "ABC0001" のように書かれたものを数える」等は (自分で) 書けませんか？

Answer (score 1):

入力ファイルの名前を `input.dat` だとして、以下。

```py
import io
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('input.dat', 'r') as f:
    count = [*Counter(re.split(r'[ .]', l)[1] for l in f).items()]

print(count)

# [('ABC0001', 2), ('ABC0002', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

以下の方法でもできます。
ファイル名'data.txt'

```
count_d = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        key = l.split(".",1)[1].split(" ",1)[0]
        count_d[key] = count_d.get(key, 0) + 1
print(count_d)

# {'ABC0001': 2, 'ABC0002': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

細かい条件やエラー処理などは考えてませんが、ざっくりとした感じで書いてみました

```
$ cat a.py
import re
import pprint

pattern = '[^\.]+\.([^\s]+)\s.*'
counts = {}

with open('a.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    key = re.match(pattern, line).group(1)
    counts.setdefault(key, 0)
    counts[key] += 1

pprint.pprint(counts)
```

入力データをファイル 'a.txt' とした場合以下のような実行結果になります。

```
$ python a.py
{'ABC0001': 2, 'ABC0002': 1}
```